# I want to display items from mySQL database in grid form using php but i'm getting this

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to display records from my database in div and in a grid format using php. I want to set it to display 3 items in a row and then create another row and then display another 3 items continuously until the set limit but unfortunately only one item is showing. Seems there is something wrong with the php code somewhere which i don't know. Please someone should help me figure it out. The code is below

```
 <?php
 <!--for image upload-->

session_start();
$_SESSION['message']="";


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','auction');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$item_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
$item_description = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['item_description']);
$item_image_path = $mysqli-
>real_escape_string('Images/item_img/'.$_FILES['item_image']['name']);

<!--make sure file is of image type-->
if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['item_image']['type'])) {
    if (copy($_FILES['item_image']['tmp_name'], $item_image_path)) {
        $_SESSION['item_name'] = $item_name;
        $_SESSION['item_description'] = $item_description;  
        $_SESSION['item_image'] = $item_image_path;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO items (item_name, item_image, item_description)
                VALUES('$item_name', 
'$item_image_path','$item_description')";
        if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Item Upload Successful!";
        } 
        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "file upload failed";
        }

    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "file copying failed";
        }
 }
     else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "please upload gif, jpg, png";
 }

}

?>
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10")
or die($mysqli->error);

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload item</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.main.css">
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="style.css">
 <!--for countdown timer--> 
    <script>
var seconds = 60*60;
function secondPassed() {
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
}
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + 
remainingSeconds;
if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
} else {
    seconds--;
}
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!--to display records from database-->
        <div class = "row c-head mar-pad">
            <?php
            $A=0;
                while ($auction = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>
                <?php
                if ($A%3==0):?> 

                <div class = "">
                    <h4><?=$auction['item_name']?></h4>
                    <img src='<?=$auction['item_image']?>' class='img-
responsive'>
                    <span id="countdown" class="timer">how</span>
                    <button class ="c-button" name ='bid'>Bid Now!</button>
                </div>
                <?php $A++;?>
                <?php endif;?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        </div>



        <!--for file upload form-->
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" 
action="auction_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1><?=$_SESSION['message']?></h1>
            <div class=" form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <INPUT type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name" 
required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Image:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <INPUT type="file" class="form-control" name="item_image" 
accept="image/*" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="item_description" required>
</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8"> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
name="upload">Upload</button>
  </div> 
</div> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ps: there is a php opening tag **<?php** at the top but i couldn't get it to display here in stackoverflow

Comment: You only output the record if `$A % 3 == 0`

Comment: i don't understand. Can you explain a little bit

Comment: In your code is an if block containing the above logic.  That means that only every third record is displayed.  Since you put in the if, you can add an else to deal with the other two cases.  It sounds like  you meant to end the current row and add a new one in cases where $A % 3 == 0, so you should add code to display the other two rows without ending the current row in an else.

Comment: I have added the else code to display the other rows but it's not still in a grid form. How i can i make it to display in grid? Here is the code i added `<?php
      else:
     ?>
     <div class = "">
      <h4><?=$auction['item_name']?></h4>
      <img src='<?=$auction['item_image']?>' class='img-responsive'>
      <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
      <button class ="c-button" name ='bid'>Bid Now!</button>
      </div>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you intend on doing "new row", by wrapping the whole row in some kind of element, or just by using a `<br>`, so we'll assume br.  Give this a try:

```
<?php
  while ($auction = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>
  <div class = "">
    <h4><?=$auction['item_name']?></h4>
    <img src='<?=$auction['item_image']?>' class='img-
responsive'>
    <span id="countdown" class="timer">how</span>
    <button class ="c-button" name ='bid'>Bid Now!</button>
  </div>
  <?php
    if ($A % 3 == 2) echo "<br>";  // new row after every third item
    $A++;
  endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Did exactly as instructed but it didn't work. Still not showing in grid form. What about the else statement? Don't you think it's necessary?

Comment: it displays all vertical

Comment: Well you need some css to make the divs display in a row, because divs naturally follow each other vertically.  `display: inline-block` on those divs with no class, so give them a class and set the css

Comment: still. Nothing changed

Comment: i got it to work finally by including the `max-width:` and `max-height:` in the styling   but the displays are uneven though.

Comment: If you need help with that it needs to be a new question.